# Does the function $f(x)=1-(1-x)^n$, $x\in[0,1]$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, have some relative tight lower or upper bound?

Tags: polynomials, asymptotics

Does the function $f(x)=1-(1-x)^n$, $x\in[0,1]$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, have some relative tight lower or upper bound?

Any hit or comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is continuous on a closed and bounded interval $[0,1]$, hence is bounded and also attains its upper ans lower bound in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

$0 \leq x  \leq 1 , -1  \leq x < 0 , 0  \leq 1-x  \leq 1, 0 \leq (1-x)^n  \leq 1, -1  \leq -(1-x)^n  \leq 0 , 0  \leq 1-(1-x)^n  \leq 1$

lower bound = 0